# left join query is not working in php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using left join query in my php script. The code which i am using is

```
$tot = "SELECT
                        c.id,
                        c.name AS companyname,
                        m.companyid,
                        m.name AS naam
                        FROM
                        org c
                        LEFT JOIN login m ON c.id = m.companyid
                    ";
        $query = $con->query($tot);

        $total = $query->num_rows;
```

it is giving this error to me "**Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in on line **$total = $query->num_rows;**
"

But when i am using this line of code it is giving total num of rows easily to me. The code i am using is

```
$tot = "SELECT * FROM org GROUP BY id ORDER BY dateadded DESC";
        $query = $con->query($tot);

        $total = $query->num_rows;

        echo $total;
```

it is working absolutely fine. SO what is the wrong thing i am doing in above code.

Comment: You have a comma before the `FROM`.  I vote to close these as simple typographical errors.  And, you should look at the error from the *database*, not simply the fact that the query did not run.

Comment: I have removed comma but still it is giving same error. So don't close this.

Comment: Run the query directly in the MySQL's console and see what you're getting.

Comment: actually if i am passing single argument from other table then it is working fine but not for multiple column names. Like it is working for single m.companyid but not for m.companyid, m.name